# How do I link two applications that are not connected in any way, even by programming languages?

Tags: python, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm a beginner, I'm currently studying arduino and working with it. I have created a small circuit that, at the touch of a button, outputs true ( 1 ) or false (0) to the Arduino IDE console. I had an idea: what if I create a python game with a controller on this chip. I have a question: how can I, roughly speaking, pull information from the Arduino IDE console and process it in python code. ( From Arduino IDE to Pycharm )
I'm sorry if there was such a question, keep in mind that I'm a beginner :)

I haven`t tried anything because i don`t even know what to try :).
I expect taking information from Arduino console, transferring it to python code and doing something with it.
I can provide you screenshots if you need.

Comment: You'll need to actually retrieve those outputs via python. I'd look for a tutorial on how to get python connected to arduino and how to read pin/sensor values. You don't want to try connecting IDEs together, it's not necessary

Comment: You are basically asking about [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), for which there are a number of solutions.

Comment: usually, i would say, please provide the code. But its great to see the community answering a question like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having the Arduino print the values you want into the serial and then have python connect to the serial, that the Arduino is connected to and read the values being sent. I would recommend using `pyserial` to read the serial, as I have had successful results in the past with it. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) is the PyPI page and [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) is the documentation.

Comment: So, in theory, I can run the code in the Arduino IDE and simultaneously read data from pins in my python code using pyserial? Will this method work with digital and analog pins?

Comment: With python, you read the serial, so all the Arduino has to do is use Serial.println() to send information to the serial. It should work for digital and analogue pins, as all you have to do is send the data that you read from the pins to the serial.